# Consume WCF service in Uno Platform

Tags: wcf, uno-platform

I am thinking to rewrite a WPF app on Uno Platform.
Is there a way to consume WCF data service inside a Uno Platform project?

Do I add a service reference? (Where would I implement that?) or there are other ways?

Comment: The Uno platform supports WCF programs. You can generate the proxy class from the WSDL of the WCF service and then use the proxy class to invoke the WCF service. And you can use the Web Service Reference Provider to solve the issue in VS.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add .Net Standard 2.0 project to your Uno platform solution and Add your WCF service reference to this (.Net Standard 2.0) project. After this, you can reference this (.Net Standard 2.0) project to your all other uno platform projects i.e. UWP, Andi, IOS, WASM, and others. Your WCF service available to all uno platform projects